# How to return a number from a variable in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on something in Python for myself to learn and such. The only problem, I cannot return or print a variable in a method.

```
   import math

class BulletCalc():
    bullet_type = ''
    velocity = 0.0
    zero = 0.0
    muzzle_height = 0.0

    target_angle = 0.0
    target_distance = 0.0

    gravity = 9.8


    def time_air(self):
        sqrtvalue = 2*self.muzzle_height
        sqrtvalue = sqrtvalue/self.gravity
        timein = sqrt(sqrtvalue)
    def drop(self, time_air):
        final_drop = self.muzzle_height - 1/2
        final_drop = final_drop * self.gravity
        final_drop = final_drop * time_air.timein
        final_drop = final_drop**2    
        print(final_drop)

Fiftyc = BulletCalc()
Fiftyc.bullet_type = '50 Caliber'
Fiftyc.velocity = 928.0
Fiftyc.muzzle_height = 0.3
```

I am trying to print Final Drop, in the drop method. It will not print anything. I don't know why. Sorry, I am new to classes in Python. Thanks! I have already tried return final drop, and all of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code Working. What you're trying to do should look like
the code bellow. Even improvements could have been made.

```
import math

class BulletCalc(object):

    def __init__(self, bullet_type, velocity, muzzle_height):
        """
            Class constructor. Should pass the values here """

        self.bullet_type = bullet_type
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.muzzle_height = muzzle_height
        self.gravity = 9.8


    def time_air(self):
        sqrtvalue = 2*self.muzzle_height
        sqrtvalue = sqrtvalue/self.gravity
        timein = math.sqrt(sqrtvalue)
        return timein

    def drop(self):
        final_drop = self.muzzle_height - 1/2
        final_drop = final_drop * self.gravity
        final_drop = final_drop * self.time_air()
        final_drop = final_drop**2    
        print(final_drop)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Fiftyc = BulletCalc(
                        bullet_type = '50 Caliber', 
                        velocity = 928.0, 
                        muzzle_height = 0.3 )
    Fiftyc.drop()
```

Comment: Thanks, but since I want to know why this works. Again, I am new to classes in Python. Why do I need to define a init, instead of a regular class. Also, with the Fiftyc, why does it need to what the if statement? Thanks!

Comment: when you call Fiftyc = BulletCalc() the class will call the method __init__ to instantiate the object. It's like a class constructor in Object oriented languages.

Comment: Don't forget to click the flag (correct) to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

You must not forget to actually call the method!:

```
Fiftyc.drop()
```

Fill the brackets with the value you want for `time_air`

---

Edit:
Change your code to this

```
def time_air(self):
    sqrtvalue = 2*self.muzzle_height
    sqrtvalue = sqrtvalue/self.gravity
    timein = sqrt(sqrtvalue)
    return timein

def drop(self, time_air):
    final_drop = self.muzzle_height - 1/2
    final_drop = final_drop * self.gravity
    final_drop = final_drop * time_air.timein
    final_drop = final_drop**2    
    print(final_drop)

Fiftyc = BulletCalc()
Fiftyc.bullet_type = '50 Caliber'
Fiftyc.velocity = 928.0
Fiftyc.muzzle_height = 0.3 

Fiftyc.drop(Fiftyc.time_air()) # call drop() with the return value  of time_air()
```

Note the added return statement in `time_air` method and using that return value to call the `drop` method on the last line

Comment: So how would I get it so it reads the number from timein? In time_air, that is

Comment: This works, except for the fact of it saying - sqrt not defined. Isn't sqrt the math function for Square root?

Answer (score 0):

Simply calling *Fiftyc.drop()* will not solve your problem.

There are many problems:

1. must have the __ init __, usually named class constructor.
2. self reference to make a variables visible to all methods of the class is absent.
3. passing a method as an argument  of another method looks bad.
4. using sqrt instead of math.sqrt()
5. variables loose in the middle of the class body
   ...